# App submit on Azure Marketplace failed with code "1000.3.1" AAD Single Sign-On

Tags: azure, multi-tenant, azure-marketplace

I am creating a web app, in which a user can access my app by submitting basic info like name, email, password, etc.

I also added a button for `Sign up with Azure Active Directory`. To integrate this I created an application on https://portal.azure.com. This application is `Multi-tenanted` so that users of external tenants can access my app (means any user can access). I am collecting only basic info like name, email. Everything is working file.

But when I submitted my web app to `Azure Marketplace`, they replied this with following message:

**Your submission has failed validation tests - 1000.3.1**

[image]

When I investigated `1000.3`, It told me this:
[image]

But I am confused, that how I can implement `Azure Active Directory Single Sign-On (AAD SSO)` on a multi-tenant app? As I know AAD SSO is on the organization level, how I can apply this in the `multi-tenant` app? Or am I missing something?

Please help me, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable multi tenancy support feature in Azure AD. For guidelines and more details, refer to - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/marketplace/enable-appsource-marketplace-using-azure-ad

If problem persist contact [Partner Center Support](https://support.microsoft.com/getsupport?wf=0&tenant=ClassicCommercial&oaspworkflow=start_1.0.0.0&locale=en-us&supportregion=en-us&pesid=16230&ccsid=636565784998876007).

Comment: Thanks Sadiqh for your reply, but I already created app on `Azure Portal > App Registration` which is `Multi-tenanted`, Should I need to enable `multi tenancy support feature` in some other place also?